# Mixing code with markup in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Can we do something like

```
<tr id="prod<%:item.ProductId%>">
```

in Razor to produce

I tried

```
<tr id="prod@item.ProductId">
```

which did not work. It rendered `<tr id="prod@item.ProductId">`
I am looking for -

```
<tr id="prod1234">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have to use the `@()` around your particular model value like so:

```
<div id="prod@(item.ProductId)"></div>
```

The reason for this is because the `prod@item.ProductId` looks like an email address to the parser and by default the parser tries to ignore email addresses so you don't have to do something silly like `john@@doe.com` as emails are common enough that it would be annoying to do every time. So the people working on the razor parser just figured: "if it looks like an email, ignore it". So that's why you're having this particular issue.

Comment: Yup. something@something.something will cause it. We could put more smarts in it to actually make it understand REAL and VALID email addresses, but that would probably slow down perf for not much benefit.  @() tells the parser "this is code all up in here so treat it like code no matter what".  You should find that you don't have to use it very often though.

Comment: Considering the performance loss is only on initial compile you're probably not losing much. In addition, I find that I generally use this particular pattern more often than an actual email address anyway so I'm not saving my keystrokes here. :)